# Intuitive definition of eigenvalues of AB^{-1}

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, intuition

I am wondering if there is a initiative definition of the eigenvalues (or even the matrix itself) of $AB^{-1}$?

Comment: The question is not clear. The definition of an eigenvalue of a matrix $C$ is as usual, also for $C=AB^{-1}$. Do you want to have a connection to the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Ceterum censeo: questions containing "intuitive" or "intuition" should be deleted and new ones rejected. It isn't a mathematical notion, so it attracts mere opinions. Intuition can't be explained, it can only be acquired by exercise. Emphasis: by *doing* exercises, not by watching them done.